# Linux Mint audio: only HDMI audio is displayed

Tags: linux-mint, audio, pulseaudio, intel

After a fresh installation of Linux Mint on my laptop I notice that audio isn't working, and I see dummy input/output. After this I had tried a lot of solutions.

After adding

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` I could see only HDMI output. This mean that headphone and integrated speaker are unavailable.

This seems like that SO can't know about internal speaker, microphone and audio jack.

How could I fix?

My system information:

[**System info**](https://termbin.com/kr2e)

[`dmesg -l err,warn`](https://termbin.com/1fx4)

#### Update

I tried different kernels: 5.11, 5.8 and 5.4.
This is a new laptop, this is the first installation. I don't know if should work...

Today, something strange has happened. I connect my headphones to randomly check if something has been changed (I don't know why) and I heard some noise from the laptop speakers. Then I try to put my smartphone line out in the computer jack with an AUX cable. And I can hear the sound of the smartphone thought the speakers. When I change the volume, nothing happened. Why? It could be some physical problem of the sound card?

##### Removing my addiction in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

`aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

#### Update 2

`find /lib/modules -type f -name snd-es\*`

```
/lib/modules/5.11.0-22-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-es1968.ko
/lib/modules/5.11.0-22-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-es1938.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-74-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-es1968.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-74-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-es1938.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-77-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-es1968.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-77-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-es1938.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-59-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-es1968.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-59-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-es1938.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-es1968.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-es1938.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-37-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-es1968.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-37-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-es1938.ko
```

`find /lib/modules -type f -name snd-sb\*`

```
/lib/modules/5.11.0-22-generic/kernel/sound/isa/sb/snd-sb-common.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-74-generic/kernel/sound/isa/sb/snd-sb-common.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-77-generic/kernel/sound/isa/sb/snd-sb-common.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-59-generic/kernel/sound/isa/sb/snd-sb-common.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/kernel/sound/isa/sb/snd-sb-common.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-37-generic/kernel/sound/isa/sb/snd-sb-common.ko
```

`lspci -k`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake Host Bridge (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake Host Bridge
00:00.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation GeminiLake [UHD Graphics 600] (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 605
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Device 1c6c:122a
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, snd_sof_pci
00:0f.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Trusted Execution Engine Interface (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Trusted Execution Engine Interface
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:12.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor SATA Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - SATA
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:13.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port (rev f6)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:13.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port (rev f6)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:13.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port (rev f6)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:16.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO I2C Host Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO I2C Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO I2C Host Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO I2C Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b0 (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b2 (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:17.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b4 (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:17.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b6 (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:17.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b8 (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:17.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31ba (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:18.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:18.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:18.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:18.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:19.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO SPI Host Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO SPI Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:19.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO SPI Host Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO SPI Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:19.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO SPI Host Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO SPI Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:1c.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor SDA Standard Compliant SD Host Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor SDA Standard Compliant SD Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
00:1e.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 31d0 (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor LPC Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
00:1f.1 SMBus: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Gaussian Mixture Model (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8821ce
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce
```

`apt list --installed | grep alsa`

```
alsa-base/focal,focal,now 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5 all [installed]
alsa-topology-conf/focal,focal,now 1.2.2-1 all [installed]
alsa-ucm-conf/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 1.2.2-1ubuntu0.8 all [installed]
alsa-utils/focal-updates,now 1.2.2-1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-alsa/focal-updates,focal-security,now 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: +1 For dmesg -l err,warn

Comment: You got **lots** of HDA and codec related errors in your dmesg. If it was working before, try using different kernels (ideally, including the one you had before; you can install different kernels without changing everything), and see if the issue persists. If it worked on an old kernel, but doesn't work on the newest kernel, it's a regression problem and needs a bugreport for the kernel.

Comment: Back out of the your additions to the modprobe file.. Then type "aplay -l". Most likely you need to modify pluseaudio - or the /etc/pulse/default.pa file.

Comment: @CinaedSimson what could I edit in /etc/pulse/default.pa file

Comment: Try restarting pulseaudio: "pulseaudio -k".

Comment: @CinaedSimson I had already tried. No changes.

Comment: Please post "lspci --k". When you write , there's no audio, did the audio ever work?  And since it's a Pentium, I presume you have a ISA sound card installed. Try "/sbin/modprobe snd-es18xx" and/or " /sbin/modprobe snd-sb16" followed by "pluseaudio -k" (this just restarts pulsaudio and you make changes) and see what happens.

Comment: Actually try "find /lib/modules -type f -name snd-es\\*" and "find /lib/modules -type f -name snd-sb\\*" - the numbers on drivers may vary. These kernel drivers are on Deiban Buster running kernel version  4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19).

Comment: @CinaedSimson The audio never worked. I updated the post with the new output from the command. My CPU is Intel Celeron J4125 (more information in System Info link in the question)

I tried "/sbin/modprobe snd-es18xx" and/or " /sbin/modprobe snd-sb16"  but the output was "not found in directory /lib/modules/5.11.0-22-generic"

Comment: Okay, the EISA errors sent me down the wrong path. Change: "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" to "options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1".

Comment: @CinaedSimson Unfortunately after replaced "options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1" in audio setting I can't see any card available.

Comment: Please remove the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file - or just move it out of the  /etc/modprobe.d directory. Note, it's kernel "snd-hda-intel.conf" file - not an "alsa-base.conf" file. Please post the output of "apt list --installed | grep alsa". It's possible you don't have alsa installed. If alsa is not installed, try "apt install alsa-oss alsa-utils".

Comment: @CinaedSimson I made a lot of tries. I try to delete the file but nothing happened, the same "Dummy Output". I edited the text with the output that you request. I also try the new kernel of Linux Mint but without success.

Comment: What versions of  alsa-oss and alsa-utils are installed?